# Is there a way to use environment variables with Ninja?

Tags: build, environment-variables, ninja

I have the following ninja file because I could not find a way to pass environment variables to ninja steps:

```
rule init
 command = sh init.sh

rule plan
 command = sh plan.sh

rule apply
 command = sh apply.sh


build plan: plan
build init: init
build apply: apply

default plan
```

I would like to skip using shell scripts and capture all the steps in Ninja. I am not sure if this is supported at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a design decision of Ninja not to do that. If you need to pass in any parameter to Ninja the supported way to generate the build file with a build generator.

Comment: For completeness, [there is an old bugrepot for that](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1002). Apparently Ninja may start supporting that at some point, given that α) the report is open as of writing this comment, β) this feature improves speed, so it belongs to design goals of the project γ) from reading the discussion I can't say there's any real push against it, more that nobody gives an ack for accepting such feature into the project. So… stay tuned :)